# Question about Madonna's first single?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-edge-of-reason, bridget-jones-diary

In the movie **Bridget Jones's Diary - The Edge of Reason**, during the Law Council Dinner, everyone participates in the quiz which covers many topics. During the last round (topic - Contemporary culture) the question is "What was the name of Madonna's first UK single?"
To this question Bridget says everyone thinks it's **Holiday** and it's not and she chimes **Lucky Star**. But later her answer is wrong and **Holiday** is the right answer.
According to google, **Holiday** is Madonna's third single. Was this bit of information jumbled just for the movie plot perspective?

Comment: The differentiation could be between 'Madonna's first single' & 'Madonna's first **hit** single'. Are you absolutely certain of the wording?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Bridget Jones movies are set in the UK.  Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madonna_singles_discography) and [Official Charts](http://www.officialcharts.com/artist/28948/madonna/) (who collate UK record sales data) Holiday is indeed the first single to "chart" in the UK.

I cannot determine whether "Everybody" and "Burning Up" were sold in the UK, but their omission from Official Charts indicates that even if they were released they were not widely distributed and didn't officially get recorded as charting singles.

I've not seen the Edge of Reason, but a typical "pub quiz" in the UK would consider Holiday the correct answer.  This isn't a movie mistake, even if it were technically incorrect, it wouldn't be out of the ordinary for it to be the answer in a quiz.